# Increasing the number of suggests shown in omnibox

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it in anyway possible to increase the number of suggests that your extension may show in the omnibox?

By default it looks like 5 rows is the limit. I've read about a command line switch to change the number of rows (`--omnibox-popup-count`) but I am really interested in dynamically being able to set this in my extension.

5 rows isn't really enough for the information my extension want to show.

Comment: I don't know this for sure, but I'd anticipate this limit isn't negotiable because it could be abused easily.

Comment: @Jimmy, I guess you are right. The sad thing is that I can't get the switch working either so I'm stuck with the default 5 rows. What I would like to do is to show url suggestions depending on the input from the user and while it wouldn't result in 100 rows returned, 5 is just not enough :(

Comment: If it's not in `chrome://flags/`, maybe you don't have a new enough build (the "canary" build, for example).

Comment: Yeah this sucks! Chrome can't even find my bookmarks when I start typing the URL! It shows irrelevant search suggestions instead! Opera was better, and showed your bookmarks first, all of them!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fact there is no more `--omnibox-popup-count` flag
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40083

So I think there is no way to enlarge the omnibox.

Comment: That's too bad. I can understand if the developers don't want an extension to be able to tinker with this value, but the switch should really be an option. This limitation makes the omnibox crippled imho.

Comment: Indeed, I have used extended (10 rows) omnibox, which was very useful for me, and one day it suddenly stopped working. Maybe it was caused by some security issue - we have to trust Chrome(ium) Team that they are doing their best. Ps. please mark my answer as correct to make moderators happy ;)

Comment: Looking at the issue above apparently their "best" was to remove the option entirely instead of fixing it when someone sets it to 0 and that crashes Chrome. And no answer to the many people asking them to restore the feature.

Comment: **There is now!**  chrome://flags/#omnibox-ui-max-autocomplete-matches .  Credit goes to @version365 below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694725/increasing-the-number-of-suggests-shown-in-omnibox/47806290#47806290

Answer (score 18):

### [Update 2018 - thanx version365 & Aaron!]

» Not hardcoded anymore! chrome://flags/#omnibox-ui-max-autocomplete-matches . Credit goes to @version365 answering below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/47806290/234309 « – Aaron Thoma

---

..[historical] detail: since the removal of --omnibox-popup-count flag (http://codereview.chromium.org/2013008) in May 2010 the number [was] hardcoded:

```
const size_t AutocompleteResult::kMaxMatches = 6;
```

[a discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-discuss/biBddM_JoQ0) two years later on the chromium-discuss mailing list about the 'Omnibox default configuration' "concluded"

> "On lower performing machines generating more result would slow down the result display. The current number look like a good balance."

[which is not a very valid argument, considering the probably infinitesimal overhead retrieving more items than the hard-wired number]

why the heck is there no chromium fork that removes stupid UX limitations like this (or the no tabbar in fullscreen mode)^^

Comment: **Not hardcoded anymore!** chrome://flags/#omnibox-ui-max-autocomplete-matches . Credit goes to @version365 answering below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47806290/234309

Answer (score 14):

Since there is no more `--omnibox-popup-count` flag; you can use another flag which is new.

`chrome://flags/#omnibox-ui-max-autocomplete-matches` lets you select a maximum of  12 rows.

Comment: This should become the accepted answer now. Unfortunately the OP is no more active.